# Is there a way to calculate DISTINCTCOUNT as SUMX in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I want to calculate the distinct sum for every row in a dataset.

I have tried to combine `SUMX` and `DISTINCTCOUNT`, without a good result.

When combining `SUMX` and `DISTINCTCOUNT` I get the wrong figures:

```
SUMX (
    VALUES ( d_CXMeasure[CX Measure Code] );
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( d_Response[ResponseId] );
        FILTER ( f_CX; f_CX[CX Measure Code] = "RCX_TOP_IM" )
    )
)
```

If I only use `DISTINCTCOUNT` I get the correct value on the totals, the same amount is expected for every row in the column

```
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( f_CX[ResponseID] );
    FILTER ( f_CX; f_CX[CX Measure Code] = "RCX_TOP_IM" )
)
```

```
        Result  Expected Result
        225     999
        118     999
        352     999
        399     999
        230     999
        117     999
        239     999
        162     999
        142     999
        204     999
        399     999
TOTALS  999     999
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are splitting out by `d_CXMeasure[CX Measure Code]` if you want the sum to ignore that, but in any case, you should be able to get your Expected Result by removing the filter context like this:

```
SUMX (
    VALUES ( d_CXMeasure[CX Measure Code] );
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( d_Response[ResponseId] );
        FILTER ( f_CX; f_CX[CX Measure Code] = "RCX_TOP_IM" );
        ALL( d_CXMeasure[CX Measure Code] )
    )
)
```